# C++ invalid comparator

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a strange problem, maybe I'm missing something obvious but I can't fiugre out.

Here is the C++ code that throws the assert:

```
int compareByX(const Vector2D &a, const Vector2D &b)
{
    if (a.x < b.x) // if i put a.x > b.x nothing changes
        return -1;
    return 1;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double pts[6] = { 5, 34, 3, 54, 10, 34 };
    std::vector<Vector2D> points;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i += 2)
        points.push_back({ pts[i],pts[i + 1] });
    std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(), compareByX);
}
```

what happens is that first point (3, 54) is tested against (5, 34), and then viceversa.
At that point the assert (invalid comparator) is thrown. But as I see it its right to return -1 as 3 is lesser than 5 and then return 1 since 5 is more than 3...

Can you tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: `sort` expects the comparison function to return `true` (`1`) or `false` (`0`). What do you think happens with `-1`? What about this way of implementing `compareByX`: `{ return a.x < b.x; }`?

Comment: [This `std::sort` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) should be helpful.

Comment: Now i get it, thanks! Thought i was working with qsort :/

Comment: for qsort, you still need to return 0 on equality.

Comment: Yeah, but first i started with: double diff =a.x-b.x ;
  return (double(0) < diff) - (diff < double(0)); And then since i had the assert i tried to make the simplest function, and then i was like wtf

Comment: you already know the answer, but for the question it would be good if you mention what assert you are talking of

Comment: btw what is a `SisVector2D` ?

Comment: I renamed the other to make it more clear, but i forgot the b. Its just a struct with two double x and y. I have now edited the question

Answer (score 9):

The invalid comparator assert was thrown because the function returned -1 and 1, while std::sort takes only true or false in order to have a weak strict ordering.

By changing the function to:

```
bool compareByX(const Vector2D &a, const Vector2D &b)
{
   return a.x < b.x;
}
```

Everything works as expected.

In the end it was indeed a very obvious mistake.

Comment: strictly speaking your answer is wrong. The comparator is only required to return something that is implicilty convertible to `bool`, thus returning `int` is fine. The real problem was that your comparator yielded `compareByX(a,b) == true` and `compareByX(b,a) == true` at the same time, which means no strict ordering. See [here](http://ideone.com/SrXVGP) for a working example where the comparator returns an `int` but is completely fine

Answer (score 3):

According to the reference for [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) a comparator must:

> comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of Compare) **which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second**. 
>   The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);

I guess that what you really want is something as the following:

```
   std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(), 
         [] (const Vector2D& a1, const Vector2D&a2){return a1.x < a2.x;}
      );
```

Comment: the `should be` in the quote isnt that accurate. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) for the more precise statement: "return type: implicitly convertible to bool". Anyhow, the part you put in bold is what caused the problem (while returning `int` or `bool` doesnt really matter)

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, but from the point of view of the functions using the comparator it does not really matter. What they see is `true` or `false`. It does not matter that you return `non-zero` for `true` (or whatever other implicitly convertible to bool) as soon you know how implicit conversion works. Thanks for pointing that out that reference!

Comment: no problem, I just saw that OPs own answer got that point wrong, and thought it would be worth mentioning here also just to avoid misunderstanding

Answer (score 2):

You'll get this error if your sort function returns the same item even when the parameters are reversed.